# CSS Grid - the column wrap completely fills the last row

Tags: css, css-grid

I have CSS grid with several columns. Minimal column width is 100px. Then I would like to wrap columns, but after wrap i want to in the last row as many columns as in the remaining rows. For exapmle I don't want to 3 cells in first row, and 1 in last row.

I don't want to expand last row cell, but move more cells in to the last row and expand ALL cells

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr))
    }
 
 .element {
 height: 50px;
 border: 2px solid red;
 }
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you will need media query for this

Answer (score -1):

You can use a flex box instead

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element element-100"></div>
</div>
```

```
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.element {
  flex: 1 0 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
.element-100 {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't need to expand last row cell, but move more cells to last row and expand ALL cells width

Comment: Oh, ok, I see you clarfied your question, in that case you would have to use either media queries (if the number of elements is always known) or probably use javascript if the number is dynamic, there is no easy solution to that.